# AuthorizationCodeReceived event not firing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin, openid-connect

I'm attempting to implement the OpenId Connect middleware in a an ASP.NET MVC 5 (.Net Framework) application.

In my `AccountController.cs` I send an OpenID Connect sing-in request. I have another OpenId connect middleware implemented which is why I specify that the middleware I want to challenge against is "AlternateIdentityProvider".

```
    public void SignIn()
    {
        HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
            "AlternateIdentityProvider");
    }
```

Upon issuing a challenge against the middleware, the `RedirectToIdentityProvider` event in `Startup.cs` fires and I am redirected to the provider for sign in. However, after successfully signing in I am redirected to the specified redirect uri with the state and code parameters added as query parameters i.e. http://localhost:63242/singin-oidc/?state=State&code=AuthorizationCode (parameters removed for brevity), which results in a 404 as no such route exists in my application.

Instead  I expected the successful signin to trigger the `AuthorizationCodeReceived` event where I can implement my additional logic. In fact none of the other events ever trigger.

I have implemented an almost identical solution in ASP.Net Core 2.1 and here I am able to step through the different events as they trigger.

The relevant code of my current `Startup.cs` is shown below. Note that the OpenId provider throws an error if the inital request include reponse_mode and some telemetry parameters, hence these are removed during the initial `RedirectToIdentityProvider` event.

Any ideas why the callback from the OpenId provider is not getting picked up in the middleware?

```
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions("AlternateIdentityProvider")
        {
            ClientId = { { Client Id } },
            ClientSecret = { { Client Secret } },
            Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId,
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code,
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost:63242/singin-oidc",
            MetadataAddress = { { Discovery document url } },

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Redirecting to identity provider for sign in..");

                    context.ProtocolMessage.EnableTelemetryParameters = false;
                    context.ProtocolMessage.ResponseMode = null;

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },

                AuthorizationCodeReceived = context => {

                    Debug.WriteLine("Authorization code received..");
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },

                SecurityTokenReceived = context =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Token response received..");
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },

                SecurityTokenValidated = context =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Token validated..");
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5):

I was encountering the same issue.  I am trying to plug in Owin into our legacy WebForms app.

For me, I had to do the following:

1) Change the application manifest of the application definition on Azure to set the "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow" property to **true** from **false**.

1. Go to the **Azure Portal**,
2. Select to **Azure Active Directory**
3. Select **App Registrations**
4. Select your app.
5. Click on **Manifest**
6. Find the value **oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow** and change it's value to **true**
7. Click **Save**

2) In your startup.cs file, change the following:

**ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code**

to

**ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken**

Once, I did those two things, the SecurityTokenValidated and AuthorizationCodeReceived started firing.

Though, I am not sure this is the right way to go or not.  Need to do more reading.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, that would be a possible workaround, but unfortunately the OpenId Connect provider that I am integrating against is not Azure. I do not have an option to make those changes with the one I am using, but I have left a ticket with their support team. Will update here when I get an answer..

Answer (score 1):

Please be aware that the OpenId Connect implementation in .Net Framework only support response_mode=form_post. (See [closed GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetKatana/issues/189))

Since you strip the parameter in the request to the OpenId Connect provider (in your RedirectToIdentityProvider notification), then the provider will default to response_mode=query pr. the specs. (see relation between response_type and response_mode ind the [specs](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#OAuth.Responses).)

So in short the OpenId Connect middleware expects that there will come a HTTP POST (with a form body) and your provider will properly send a HTTP GET (with parameters as query-string).

Comment: I was trying to use it with MSAL which is not possible at all: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/issues/480. Had to resort to `app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication` instead.