Cant log out of Asp Net Framework Web App using OpenIdConnect Identity Provider
I have an ASP.NET Framework web application that uses AWS Cognito user pool to sign in, sign out, and assign roles to protected resources.
I can log in succesfully to the app but I cant log out correctly.
According to documentation, when hitting the log out controller you must call both:
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
and
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
The former deleted the aspnet cookie that is keeping track of the local session
The latter redirects to Cognito to delete the user's session in Cognito.
The above however didnt work. Just executing the code above doesnt prompt my app to logout of Cognito.
I was therefore advised to add a callback so that when I click logout, the following method can fire:
`RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
{
// if signing out, add the id_token_hint
if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
{
var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");
                        if (idTokenHint != null)
                        {
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                            //n.ProtocolMessage.ClientId = OidcClientId;
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = logoutredirect;
                            n.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = OidcRedirectUrl;
                            //n.ProtocolMessage.Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenId;
                            //n.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                            //n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType = OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication;
                            //n.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44309/signout-callback-oidc";
                            //See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54129602
                            n.ProtocolMessage.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.FormPost;
                            n.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44309/";

                        }
                    }

                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                }`

However, no combination of the above made my app actually redirect to Cognito to hit the logout endpoint. I even checked the network tab and no external network calls are made? Why isnt my application hitting a logout endpoint?
